# Not able to add array element to table row in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a table using jQuery. Trying to add integer elements from array to the table rows gives the error

> Uncaught TypeError: array[i].appendTo is not a function

I get this error while debugging with Chrome.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var rs = "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9";
        var array = new Array();
        array = rs.split(", ");
        var tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>').appendTo(tableHTML);
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            var trHTML = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(tbody);
            var tdHTML = $('<td align="center"></td>').html(
                    (array[i]).appendTo(trHTML)); // error here
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: `array[i]` is a string. There is no `appendTo` property on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using this solution, formulate the html, and append it dynamically to your table. You don't have to use appendTo.

You are encountering error because you are trying to appendTo a string not to html element.

```js
var tableHTML = $("#numberTable");
var rs = "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9";
var array = new Array();
array = rs.split(", ");
var html = '<tbody>';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  html += '<tr><td align="center">'+i+'</td></tr>';
}
html += '</tbody>';
tableHTML.html(html);
```

```html
<table id="numberTable" style="width:100%">
  
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var rs = "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9";
 var array = rs.split(", ");       
 var str = ''                      //Sring to append
 for(d in array)                   //for array iteration
 str+='<tr>'+d+'</tr>'             //storing array values in str
 $('#tbody_id').html(str)          //Appending value to tbody
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it